# How to protect against duplicate entries getting inserted because of database transactions in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose the code is like this:

```
function abc()
{
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    $entry = tryingToFindSomeEntry();
    if (exists($entry)) {
        updateThisEntry($data);
    }else{
        $tempEntry = createThatEntry($data);
        insertIntoDatabase($tempEntry);
    }

    //putting sleep here before committing so we can get some time;
    sleepForSeconds(30);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
}
```

Now if call this function in 3 parallel processes, none will find any entry that is `exists(entry) is false`. So all 3 processes will insert it since it has never been committed. (get commits after 30 seconds, before which all process would have read it).

I don't want to apply LOCK WRITE to a complete table, avoid read blocking for every other user. What approach should I take?

Using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Can you have another try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a table with some attribute defined as unique.

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int auto_increment primary key, x int, unique key (x));
```

In one terminal window, insert a row but do not commit yet.

```
mysql 1> start transaction;
mysql 1> insert into mytable set id = 1, x = 1;
```

In a second terminal window, confirm that you can insert another row if it does not conflict with the unique key.

```
mysql 2> insert into mytable set id = 2, x =2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

But in the second window, if you try to insert a row with a duplicate value in `x` it is blocked, even though the transaction in window 1 is still not committed.

```
mysql 2> insert into mytable set id = 3, x =1;
...hangs for 50 seconds...
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Whereas if the transaction in window 1 were to commit while the insert in window 2 is waiting:

```
mysql 1> commit;
```

Then the insert fails immediately with a duplicate key error.

```
mysql 2> insert into mytable set id = 3, x =1;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'x'
```

But if window 1 does rollback, the insert is allowed to succeed.

Comment: What a simple example, Thank you!